# Calling imported function within itself not working in Node.js, probably related to return statement and scope

Tags: javascript, node.js

My idea is to build an application that generates sudoku's and allows users to fill them in. I'm using Node and Mongo to do so. For generating the sudoku, I have imported my 'sudoku.js' into a route function. The sudoku generation in 'sudoku.js' runs fine only when I run it by itself, but not in the route.

In short, the sudoku generator picks a random number, checks whether it has already been used in the row/column/block, and if not, adds it to the array. If it has been used, the function is re-ran, until it does 'discover' a correct sudoku. The function should return an array consisting of nine arrays, each with 9 numbers.

It appears to go south when the function genSud() is called within itself. The function, as it is now, returns 'undefined'. When I comment out the function call within the function, it does return an array, but those are almost always unfinished sudoku's. If I leave out the return statement, which I think the issue is related to, it will just keep on rerunning the function until it hits the stack limit.

```
const createSudoku = {
getRandomNumber: function(array) {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
},
checkIfIn: function(array, blockNumber, blockAvailable, columnNumber, columnAvailable) {
    let availableNumbers = [];

    array.forEach(function(element) {
        if (blockAvailable[blockNumber].includes(element) && columnAvailable[columnNumber].includes(element)) {

            availableNumbers.push(element);
        }
    });
    if (availableNumbers.length === 0) {
        return false;
    };
    return availableNumbers;
},
genSud: function(callback) {
    let availableNumbers = [];
    let goodLines;
    let blockAvailable = [ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], etc, etc ]
    let columnAvailable = [ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], etc, etc ]
    let rowAvailable = [ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], etc, etc ]
    let blockNumber;
    let randomNumber;

    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

        for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            blockNumber = Math.floor(j / 3) + 3 * Math.floor(i / 3);

            availableNumbers = this.checkIfIn(rowAvailable[i], blockNumber, blockAvailable, j, columnAvailable);
            if (availableNumbers == false) {
                this.genSud(callback);
                return;
            }
            randomNumber = this.getRandomNumber(availableNumbers);

            rowAvailable[i].splice(rowAvailable[i].indexOf(randomNumber), 1);
            columnAvailable[j].splice(columnAvailable[j].indexOf(randomNumber), 1);
            blockAvailable[blockNumber].splice(blockAvailable[blockNumber].indexOf(randomNumber), 1);

            body[i].push(randomNumber);
        }
    }
    callback(body);
}
```

}

```
// createSudoku.genSud();

module.exports = createSudoku;
```

Then, in my route:

```
var sudoku = require('../sudoku.js');
var completeSudoku = sudoku.genSud(function(result) {
    return result;
});
```

I'm aware I could abandon the rerunning altogether by replacing numbers etc., but for now it's fast enough by itself. Also, I know I could store a bunch of sudoku's in a database and retrieve them, but I like the idea of generating them on the spot.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I have created a CodePen here: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OjmGMy?editors=0000

You can run it in the console using:
createSudoku.genSud();

Comment: You're returning from a callback, why? Instead try console.log and see if you get the result

Comment: Why are you even using a callback? You neither want it to be called asynchronously nor multiple times as I understand. Just use plain return values instead.

Comment: I tried the callback because at some point I suspected it might have to do with that. But even without the callback it returns undefined.

Comment: regarding `if I remove return`, try doing `return this.genSud(callback);` I haven't examined the code thoroughly, but that should get rid of the recursion issue if it's otherwise returning undefined

Comment: So the algorithm works and is fast enough, only by dropping the recursive call or omitting the return you are getting problems, do I understand this right?

Comment: Also I wouldn't use recursion and for loops in the same function... too much complexity

Comment: @user3737812 "*even without the callback it returns undefined.*" - show us that attempt, please. Most likely you forgot to `return` the result of the recursive call. The easiest solution would probably be to drop the recursion and just use a `while` loop anyway.

Comment: @Bergi The algorithm works, but when I include it in my route it returns undefined, whereas when I call the function itself separately, it works fine.

Comment: I have created a CodePen, see the edit of the initial post. It shows how the function is supposed to run. The problem occurs when I try to run it from another file.

Comment: @user3737812 There's no difference in behaviour depending on where you call it. It might just be that you had good luck and always got a valid sudoku on first try, where it will return a value. As I said, it needs to be `return this.genSud();` instead of `this.genSud(); return;`

Answer (score 0):

I have made it work by removing the callback and using @nstraub 's suggested edit. Changed:

```
if (availableNumbers == false) {
                this.genSud();
                return;
}
```

to

```
if (availableNumbers == false) {
                return this.genSud();
}
```

I'm not sure why this works, but it does solve the issue.